# Posisionamiento con React y Css

Tags: css, reactjs

Tengo un problema a la hora de posicionar una etiqueta nav dentro de un componente.

En la etiqueta nav uso position fixed, y apesar de que el elemento padre del componente esta con posision relative, no me lo reconoce como tal y se pone en posision fixed tomando como padre al componente App o al body.

Comment: Al hacer hacer una pregunta siempre pon el codigo que ya tengas asi los demas nos hacemos una idea mejor de donde esta el problema. Ademas las preguntas que no tienen codigo propio son normalmente mal recibidas.

Comment: El comportamiento que mencionas es lo normal, fixed siempre tomara como referencia el body, quizas lo que buscas es absolute que este toma como referencia el elemento padre

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta @ElFuturoLlego.

Comment: Muchas gracias @ArturoGallegos ,esa es la solucion que necesitaba.